# Python while loop for retries with exponential back offs

Tags: python, while-loop, try-except

I wrote a function that is supposed to try a function several times until this works.

```
def Retry(attempts,back_off,value):
    for i in range(attempts):
        counter = 0
        while attempts > counter:
            try:
                x = function(value)
            except:
                counter =+ 1
                delay = (counter * back_off) + 1
                print ('trying again in {} seconds'.format(delay))
                sleep(delay)
                continue
            break
        return x

result = Retry(20,2,value)
```

Each failed attempt should be followed by an exponential growing time break
i.e. second attempt after 2 seconds, third attempt after 4 seconds, fourth attempt after 8 seconds and so on. The problem is that in the function I wrote, if the first attempt fails, I just get an infinite series of lines that look like:

```
trying again in 3 seconds
trying again in 3 seconds
trying again in 3 seconds
trying again in 3 seconds
trying again in 3 seconds
trying again in 3 seconds
....
```

What am I doing wrong? why the loop is stack there?

Comment: `counter =+ 1` is an equivalent of `counter = (+1)` and it makes counter equal 1 on each iteration.

Comment: Apart from the error mentioned by Vikas, there are two more problems with your code. If the `while` loop exits because `attempts > counter` is False then `x` will be undefined, so you'll get an error when you try to return it. And the `for` loop doesn't really do anything, due to the `return x`. But if you change your code so that the `for` loop actually loops, make sure that there's a valid value being returned when the `for` falls through, or the default `None` will be returned.

Comment: Could you write an answer with on example of a polish version of my while loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The

```
counter =+ 1
```

should be

```
counter += 1
```